# Check slot of transcluded content if its empty

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty stuck now and I don't know any solution for my problem.

I've got some own components, which I fill with content projection and multi slot transclusion.

In example, I have a Card (Bootstrap) and want to set some things in a template, like header, body or a simple footer.

```
<div class="card"> 
<ng-content select="[card-header]">
<!-- Alles was hier eingefügt wird, ist weg :-) -->
</ng-content>

<ng-content select="[card-body]">
<!-- Alles was hier eingefügt wird, ist weg :-) -->
</ng-content>

<ng-content select="[card-list]">
<!-- Alles was hier eingefügt wird, ist weg :-) -->
</ng-content>
</div>
```

If I know use my component, it would looks like this:

```
<vng-control-card>
                <span card-header>
                    <fa-icon [icon]="['fas','user']"></fa-icon> Benutzerliste
                </span>
                <div card-list>
                    <vng-control-userlist [showSendButtons]="false"></vng-control-userlist>
                </div>
            </vng-control-card>
```

As you can see, there is no body, only a card-list and a header. But the body is rendered. How can I check, if there is any content for a slot? If the slot ist empty, it should not be visible.

Example:
[Rendered userlist (component)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z06Tf.png)

The yellow part is the empty slot "card-body" which is empty, but rendered and put into the dom.

Any chance to check and avoid this?

Comment: I'm also in kind of like this problem, any solution?
P.S. :- I have found some hack by using css :empty selector. Will post as a answer belower

Answer (score 1):

Found kind of a hack for this. My problem is came with angular elements. Even when the slot is empty, the DOM element is still there.

So i did this, if the slot's class is title - in css

```
.title:empty { display: none }
```

It will remove the element if the slot is empty